# Excel VBA code to stop ODBC Refresh in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, odbc

I have a VBA code to execute formula and pivot table. However, for everything to be correct I have to do a background refresh before my vba code but then after the vba code the ODBC refresh again.
Actually it does: background refresh, VBA code, ODBC refresh (auto)
Desired result: Background refresh, VBA code. (no ODBC refresh)

I do not want to break connection but just stop ODBC refresh process after my VBA code.

Fo your reference the VBA code start on workbook open.

Expected result: On workbook open do a background refresh then execute my vba code and no ODBC refresh involved after.

```
     Private Sub Workbook_Open()
```

`With Application 'Activate by default iteractive calculation
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
.Iteration = True
.MaxIterations = 1000
.MaxChange = 0.00001
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End With

DoEvents
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
DoEvents
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique3").PivotCache.Refresh
DoEvents

Startxdate = ActiveSheet.Range("C6").Value

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique3").PivotFields( _
"DATE DOCUMENT").CurrentPage = "(All)"
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Tableau croisé dynamique3").PivotFields( _
"DATE DOCUMENT")
'.PivotItems("(blank)").Visible = False
.PivotItems(Startxdate).Visible = True
End With

DoEvents
Range("A1:M1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Range("A1:M1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0", _
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=total"


DoEvents
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim qt As QueryTable

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each qt In ws.QueryTables
qt.BackgroundQuery = False
Next
Next

'ActiveWorkbook.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False 'here I need to make 
'background refresh to off to not make ODBC refresh data because I 
'already did a background refresh Workbook_Open()

End Sub`

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code, otherwise, we can't help much, except to theorize, which we really don't do here. Read [ask] or take [tour] for more info.

Comment: Code posted. Look at last line for what is needed.

Comment: Thanks for updating code. It's not clear though what you want to refresh in your workbook at the end of your code. If you want to refresh specific items only, the specify those specific items in the code, instead of using the blanket `Refresh` method. Also, I don't see anything in the code you wrote that would necessitate a workbook refresh after the first one that's called.

Comment: The refresh start automatically after my macro. I want to stop it. I want the background refresh stop, turn off... I did a refresh on start... I dont want a second refresh at the end of the macro. (please note the background refresh automatically start after the macro)

Comment: Go to the data connection settings and make sure `Refresh on Workbook Open` is not checked.

Comment: I want to do it from VBA macro. We have many files and most of them we just need to open and everything build correctly but this file I need to stop the refresh because I already did it from macro. Please note VBA Private Sub Workbook_Open() macro will start before the data connection setings (Refresh on Workbook Open)